# Display a Paragraph N times in COBOL

Tags: cobol

I am trying to call a paragraph N times using an online compiler which is **OpenCOBOL v1.1.0** This is what I am doing :

```
IDENTIFICATION DIVISION.
PROGRAM-ID. PerformNTimes.

    PROCEDURE DIVISION.
       PERFORM 3 TIMES
         DISPLAY 'IN A-PARA'
       END-PERFORM

       PERFORM B-PARA 3 TIMES.
       STOP RUN.

       B-PARA.
       DISPLAY 'IN B-PARA'
```

Why it is not calling B-PARA?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I solved it. The point is each line should end with CRLF. Added a period after the **DISPLAY** in **B-PARA** and ended each line with CRLF. You can refer [here](http://badkr.blogspot.in/2015/01/error-syntax-error-unexpected-end-of.html) to see how you can achieve this.

Comment: And if you follow my suggestion, you'll have access on your own machine to a compiler which well be more lenient for lines without the expected endings. I've often wondered how that happens. Did you just paste the example into your editor and then save the file?

Comment: @BillWoodger I copy-pasted an example from a site into an online OPENCOBOL and it was not working. So, I copy-pasted from the OPENCOBOL to Notepad++ file and updated endings and also added a DOT after B-PARA as suggested by you and it solved the problem.

Answer (score 2):

It will probably be much more convenient for you to get your own compiler. OpenCOBOL is now known as GnuCOBOL, and is available, in more up-to-date versions, from SourceForge.Net.

Your example may not be compiling. You don't show a final full-stop/period after the DISPLAY in B-PARA.

There's full support for the product and assistance with COBOL in the discussion groups at the GnuCOBOL area: https://sourceforge.net/p/open-cobol/discussion/?source=navbar